# Set kafka stream header from Int to Array[Byte] conversion

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using kafka streams on a project (using Scala) in which I need to include some Headers on the records that I'm sending to a topic. Specifically, a `Header` requires you to convert the value that you want to put on the Header (in my case `Int` and `Long`) to a `Array[Byte]`. If I try to convert an `Int` to a `Array[Byte]` using `toByte` function, I cannot recover the header from the topic (it appears as null). The only way to do it seems to be to convert it to a `String` and then use `getBytes` to store it on the header:

```
val counter: Int = 1

// counter_1 doesn't appear
context.headers().add("counter_1", Array[Byte](counter.toByte))

// counter_2 doesn't appear
context.headers().add("counter_2", ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(counter).array())

// the value 1 appears on the header counter_3.
context.headers().add("counter_3", String.valueOf(counter).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

It doesn't seem to me that converting an int to a `String` is the correct way to do it. What's the right way to do it?

I'm recovering the records using the `kafkacat` command with the `%h` option. So I would get something like this:

```
...counter_1=,counter_2=,counter_3=1,....
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that Kafka Streams sends a stream of bytes without telling the Kafka topic whether these bytes are an Integer, Double, String or other type. Kafka is not aware of sent data type, it just gets some bytes.

When you fetch messages using Kafkacat it assumes the messages are Strings. So if you have sent a String encoded to bytes it is able to display it. However, when you send Integers encoded to bytes - then most likely these integers are converted to bytes representing ASCII codes of unprintable characters and that's why Kafkacat won't display them

Comment: Headers are always bytes, though, I don't think kcat deserializes header values

Comment: The numbers [0..9] are ASCII characters (codes 48 to 57), and the default charset of the terminal is UTF-8. The first 127 representable ASCII characters are digits and letters that are the same as the first UTF-8 characters. So if kafkacat is able to print an ASCII string, shouldn't also be able to print a digit?